# Dual booted Ubuntu 19.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

Yesterday I dual booted Ubuntu 19.04 with Windows 10.I was able to work with Ubuntu for some time,today when I load Ubuntu I'am getting the following message.
[image: photo of boot error]

(My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad 330 Ryzen 5 Quad Core - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) 330-15ARR U )

Now even my Windows is crashing often and I'm not able to open Apps like Chrome,Mozilla etc.Can someone tell a safe method to get rid of Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: At the prompt write `fsck -y /dev/sda7` and press enter. Fsck will run and repair your disk partition. But the question is, why did the disk get bad? Did you shutdown youw computer hard, or is the disk bad ?

Comment: it does give you a prompt, why don't you do : `fsck /dev/sda7` like it suggests?

Comment: I tried nothing happedned I'll attach photo grah

Comment: Can someone tell me a safe way to uninstall Ubuntu,now because my Windows is also Crashing often!

Comment: @karel Thank You It helped